# java.lang.ClassCastException in java(Springboot & Mongodb) in springboot get api

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

my MessageFieldRepository is

```
package xyz.repository;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import xyz.models.MessageField;
public interface MessageFieldRepository extends CrudRepository<MessageField,String> {


    @Query(value="{'messageSchema' : ?0}" )
     List<Object[]> findByMessageSchemaId(String messageSchema );

}
```

And  MssageFieldSchemaService Class Method is

```
public JSONObject findByMessageSchema(String messageSchema) throws ParseException{
        JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject();

        List<Object[]> data =  messageFieldRepository.findByMessageSchemaId(messageSchema);
        JSONArray messageFieldJsonArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject messageFieldJsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            for (Object[] alldatastore : data) {
                messageFieldJsonObject.put("dataVal", alldatastore[0]);
                messageFieldJsonObject.put("messageSchema", alldatastore[1]);
                messageFieldJsonObject.put("dataVal", alldatastore[2]);
                messageFieldJsonObject.put("messageSchema", alldatastore[3]);
                messageFieldJsonObject.put("dataVal", alldatastore[4]);

                messageFieldJsonArray.add(messageFieldJsonObject);
            }
            jsonobject.put("fields", messageFieldJsonArray);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return jsonobject;
    }
```

this is the line where i'm getting error

```
for (Object[] alldatastore : data) {
```

Exception =>

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: cubereum.models.MessageField cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

can any one tell why this error is comming

Comment: Propably, you need to use suitable pojo class instead Object. Paste raw (string) query result from mongo.

Comment: Have you debugged the code to see what `data` contains when you receive the error?

Comment: Already tried but not working

Comment: it contains two object ,in which multiple value are present

Comment: I believe the repository should return your `cubereum.models.MessageField` instances, consider changing `List<Object[]>` to `List<MessageField>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a `CrudRepository<MessageField,String>` will return a `List<MessageField>` if you define an interface method `findByMessageSchemaId(String messageSchema );`

So you are trying to cast a `MessageField`to an array of `Object` which produces the error. So change the return type of the interface:

```
List<MessageField> findByMessageSchemaId(String messageSchema);
```

and the loop:

```
for (messageField : data) {
  // do something with messageField
}
```

Besides that your code has some logical errors:

```
messageFieldJsonObject.put("dataVal", alldatastore[0]);
messageFieldJsonObject.put("messageSchema", alldatastore[1]);
messageFieldJsonObject.put("dataVal", alldatastore[2]);
messageFieldJsonObject.put("messageSchema", alldatastore[3]);
messageFieldJsonObject.put("dataVal", alldatastore[4]);
```

You first store `alldatastore[0]` under the key *dataVal*, then you overwrite this with `alldatastore[2]` and then with `alldatastore[4]`.
Under the key *messageSchema* you store the value of `alldatastore[1]` just to overwrite it two lines later with `alldatastore[3]`. So in the end you have a JSOObject containing two elements where you probably expect it to have 5.

Comment: i'll change the all key that is not in issue but when i'm using MessageField type and itrating it then it only one object

Comment: what do you get from the repository? One object, or a list with objects? Please check this in a debugger sessiohn. Is the messageSchema parameter a unique identifier?